# Automatically create folders based on unique key

Tags: batch-file, batch-processing

I have various files with the same structure, they begin with a unique key and a hyphen followed by the name of the file. Examples below:

- 100023525_Document_1
- 100023525_Document_2
- 102008006_Document_1
- 102008006_Document_2
- 102008006_Document_3

I want to be able to generate folders for each unique key and have the files moved into them automatically. I have found the following code below written in batch that does so but puts each file into its own separate folder.

```
@echo off
for %%i in (*) do (
 if not "%%~ni" == "organize" (
  md "%%~ni" && move "%%~i" "%%~ni"
 )
)
```

This puts the following files:

[image]

to

[image]

I want the code to be able to put the initial files into folders like this, based on the unique key:

[image]

How could I modify the initial batch code to do this? Thanks!

Comment: Your question shows that you've not yet complete researching your issue. There are many examples of how to locate files with a particular extension, and pattern, and to split those filenames using a particualr character within that pattern. To begin with, your code is enumerating all files when your images clearly indicate that those files are most likely only those with a PDF extension _(Nitro icons)_. Also those `.pdf` filenames have a pattern beginning with nine digits, followed by an underscore, and you are specifically wanting to isolate those nine characters. Read the output of `for /?`.

Answer (score 0):

Note: I decided to simplify the code here.

There are probably easier and faster ways to do this, but here is one option if your files are all in the same format. You will want to do this from the folder containing your files:

```
for /f "delims=_" %%b in ('dir /b *.pdf') do (
if not exist %%b\. @mkdir "%%b"
)
for /f "tokens=1,2,3 delims=_" %%b in ('dir /b *.pdf') do (
if not exist "%%b\%%b_%%c_%%d" @echo move "%%b_%%c_%%d" "%%b\%%b_%%c_%%d"
)
```

For more information on how this works, please read the documentation on [for /f.](https://ss64.com/nt/for_f.html) Take note of how the tokens and delimiters work.

This will show you the items it will move and where. Remove `@echo` in front of move to do the actual move.

Comment: Hello, I have tried using the code but it does not move the initial files into the folders. The folders are generated but remain empty. I have removed @echo but it does not seem to work.

Comment: I successfully tested with the code provided using the exact same file names. I did fix a small issue where I had *.txt in the second for loop. Are the file name examples you provided in the exact same format as the actual files? If not, it would help if you provided actual file names.